# Is the function Riemann integrable on interval $[1, 2]$

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I am facing the following problem:

Is the given function $f$ Riemann integrable on the interval $[1, 2]$?

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
      x & \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\\\
      -x & \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}
$$

I am not sure how to prove this. I assume that the continuity is no the way how to prove this. From the density of the ratinal numbers in rational numbers I assume that this function is not Riemann integrable as we cannot find the Upper Riemann Sum nor the Lower Riemann Sum.

Therefore it violates the criteria of the Riemann Integrability:

Function $f$ is Riemann Integrable on the interval $[a,b]$ if and only if $$ \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \exists D: 0 \le S(D,f) - s(D,f) \lt \varepsilon $$

Are my assumptions correct? If not, any idea how to solve this one?

Comment: Of course you can find upper Riemann sums and lower Riemann sums for any partition $D$. But the issue is that they will be far apart, so that your Riemann integrability condition will fail for every $0<\varepsilon<2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any division $D$ of the interval $[1,2].$ Then $$s(D,f)=s(D,-x)\le s(D,-1)=-1$$
$$S(D,f)= S(D,x)\ge S(D,1)=1$$ Therefore $S(D,f)-s(D,f)\ge 2.$ The function $f$ is thus not Riemann integrable.

Comment: I am unsure if I got this right - does it contradict the Riemann Integrability criterium because we cannot find smaller epsilon that would fulfil the condition?

Comment: Yes, for example we cannot find a division for which $S(D,f)-s(D,f)< 1.$